# No CD/DVD boot option on a Lenovo B50 laptop that has had Ubuntu on it

Tags: windows-8.1, bootable-media

So yesterday I tried to install Win 8.1 instead of Ubuntu on my my Lenovo B50 laptop so I got a Win DVD and I booted from it. I erased the place where Ubuntu was installed and proceeded to make a new partition to install Win.

Apparently the DVD was corrupted because it always got stuck in the installation process.

So I got myself another one, but when I open my boot menu there is only one option which is "EFI PXE Network." (This wasn't the case before.)

And I can't find an option to boot from DVD. This happens when I use UEFI mode.

When I use legacy mode I can boot from DVD but Windows won't install because of some GPT problem.

I know that I can change my hard drive between GPT and MBR but this would result in losing the data on my hard drive which I can not have.

So I want a way to boot from DVD while I'm in UEFI mode **and not lose any data on the hard drive**.

Comment: @JakeGould I don't want a solution that will cause me to lose any data so I can't convert to MBR or delete the partition.